# How can I change status of a checkbox and a ImageButton with one click (from one or from the other)? .Net Maui

Tags: .net, checkbox, maui, imagebutton

I need to click on the ImageButton and change the status of the checkbox and vice-versa. How can I grab both names or ids, to reference?

I've include x:Name="{Binding nameFrmoCollection}" on both, but it didn't work, beause the object sender does not bring it.

This is my code:

my Xaml:

```
 <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate >
     <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ConvenioProfissional">
         <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Margin="7,2,0,6" Padding="0" BorderColor="#F0F0F0">
             <StackLayout>
                 <ImageButton Source="{Binding Convenio_Img}" Clicked="OnImageButtonClicked" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="transparent" BorderColor="transparent" BorderWidth="2" CornerRadius="10"/>
                 <CheckBox Margin="0,-35,0,0" Color="#66AEBA" HeightRequest="30"/>                               
             </StackLayout>
         </Frame>
     </DataTemplate>
 </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

My Code Behind (working for the ImageButton so far).

```
 public void OnImageButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;           

     ((ImageButton)sender).BorderWidth = 4;
     ((ImageButton)sender).BorderColor = ButtonUpTextColor;
     ((ImageButton)sender).CornerRadius = 10;
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We cannot get the control through **x:Nam**e which is in DataTemplate from code behind. Instead, we could use [Data bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/basic-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0)

Suppose we want to change the **CheckBox** `IsChecked` Property when **ImageButton** is clicked. The following is the demo I made.

*Here is the xaml file. For the ImageButton, we use **Command** instead of a **clicked event**.*  For Command binding, you may refer to [Relative Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-8.0#bind-to-an-ancestor).

```
<BindableLayout.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ConvenioProfissional">
        <Frame HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Margin="7,2,0,6" Padding="0" BorderColor="#F0F0F0">
            <StackLayout>
                <ImageButton Source="{Binding Convenio_Img}" 
                             Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPageViewModel}}, Path=ClickedCommand}" 
                             CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
                             WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="transparent" 
                             BorderColor="transparent" BorderWidth="2" CornerRadius="10"/>
                <CheckBox    IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="0,-35,0,0" Color="#66AEBA" HeightRequest="30" />
            </StackLayout>
        </Frame>
    </DataTemplate>
</BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
```

*Then comes our Model, that is **ConvenioProfissional***. In this model, we have to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**, which defines a single event named PropertyChanged. When we modify the `IsChecked` value, the UI will also update.

```
public class ConvenioProfissional : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Convenio_Img { get; set; }

    public bool isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    { 
        get
        {
            return isChecked;
        }      
                        
        set
        {
            isChecked = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsChecked)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

Finally, this is the ViewModel. We have to implement the **ClickedCommand** for **ImageButton**. Through the **CommandParameter**, we got the ConvenioProfissional instance that we clicked, and then we just modify the **IsChecked** Property for it.

```
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ConvenioProfissional>  ItemCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ConvenioProfissional>();   

    public MainPageViewModel() 
    {
        // add some test data, just ignore it
        ItemCollection.Add(new ConvenioProfissional() { Convenio_Img = "help.png", IsChecked = false });
    }

    public Command ClickedCommand 
    { 
        get
        {
            return new Command((e) =>
            {
                var obj = e as ConvenioProfissional;
                foreach(var item in ItemCollection)
                {
                    if(obj == item) 
                    { 
                        item.IsChecked = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
    }
}
```

If you have any questions, feel to ask!

Hope it helps!